# HTML and CSS - Link catch area is larger than the box model

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm working on a website, using WordPress and I've just put in a link, but the catch area of the link is much wider than the box model I've specified, I've checked to see the box model and it all looks in order. I'm really confused right now, can anyone help?

Here's the HTML behind it:

```
<h1>Vance and Hines Exhaust Systems</h1>
<a class="link-br">Online Catalogue</a> <span class="padding-l">Vance and Hines Exhaust Systems</span>
<a href="http://test">
<div class="box-link">
<img src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/harley.gif" alt="Harley Davidson Logo" />
<span>Harley Davidson</span>
</div>
</a>
<a class="link-br">Online Catalogue</a> <span class="padding-l">Vance and Hines Exhaust Systems</span>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
a > .box-link {
height: 150px;
width: 120px;
border: 1px #ccc solid;
}

.box-link {
height: 150px;
width: 120px;
margin: 5px;
text-align: center;
}

.box-link img {
margin-top: 23%;
}
```

I've replicated the problem on JS Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ParadAUX/co3p0zy3/

So it's obviously something I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres a working **[CodePen](http://codepen.io/noobskie/pen/aNLBOP)**

What i did was surround the link in a containing `div` and set the link itself to `display:inline`

```css
a > .box-link {
height: 150px;
width: 120px;
border: 1px #ccc solid;
}

.box-link {
height: 150px;
width: 120px;
margin: 5px;
text-align: center;
}

.box-link img {
margin-top: 23%;
}

.imgCont a{
  display:inline-block
}
```

```html
<h1>Vance and Hines Exhaust Systems</h1>
<a class="link-br">Online Catalogue</a> <span class="padding-l">Vance and Hines Exhaust Systems</span>
<div class="imgCont">
  <a href="http://test">
    <div class="box-link">
      <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/harley.gif" />
      <span>Harley Davidson</span>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<a class="link-br">Online Catalogue</a> <span class="padding-l">Vance and Hines Exhaust Systems</span>
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks, any idea as to why it was doing the whole massive link thing before though?

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
.box-link {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the width of anchor tag(a). Just add a div which specifies the space.

```
<div style="width:120px">//add this tag
  <a href="http://test" id="a"><div class="box-link">
  <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/harley.gif" />
  <span>Harley Davidson</span>
  </div></a>
</div>
```